# in unit testing it gives this error message

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-identity

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.
>        The system cannot find the file specified.WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.

I checked the version for Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework and its dependencies all are in same version. what is this error pointing towards? 
It also says...

> "log attempting download of new URL
>   ........Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.exe"

which is not there. what does it mean?

Comment: thanks Nkosi! im a newbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below fix as it worked for me..

for 64 bit
VS-> Test->Test Settings ->Default Process Architecture ->64 and Must Rebuild

for 32 bit
VS-> Test->Test Settings->Default Process Architecture ->86 and Must Rebuild

Hope it helps.

Comment: Many of time the issue "Could not load file or assembly" occurs with the incompatible bit type.. did u checked under properties of your test project weather its compatible with ur os version too

Comment: i have 183 test out of them 10 fails because of this error, i dont think its because of OS version.

Comment: thanks for help, but i figured out, its stupid me... i didnt added references. it required other references too.

Comment: @RGC if you figured it out then you should add what you did as the answer. Marking an answer that did not resolve your issue is misleading to others who may come across your question and try to apply the wrong fix.

Comment: the reason was stupid, i forgot to add microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework and its dependencies in the reference form nuget package for unit test project. Thanks Nkosi for reminding the importance